# If I type a to be "No", it gives me what's in bold, both parts!. Anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

So... This is my problem :( anyone know a fix? It outputs: "Ok, try again then. " and "ERROR: You have not in-putted yes or no! " Would really like to fix this. Trying to make a text based game, because they can be fun sometimes, especially with a good storyline

```
# Infinite loop until yes or Yes is in-putted
while True:
# Ask name
    name = input("What is your name? ")

    if len(name) == 0:
        print("Invalid name, cannot leave blank!")
    if len(name) > 0:
        a = input("Are you sure this is your name? (Yes/No) ")
# What yes/no/anything else does
    if a == "yes":
        print("Cool name", name)
        break
# HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
    if a == "No":
        print("Ok, try again then. ")

    if a == "Yes":
        print("Cool name", name)
        break

    if a == "no":
        print("Ok, try again then. ")
# AND HERE:
    else:
        print("ERROR: You did not input yes or no! ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It outputs: "Ok, try again then. "*

Ok. That is expected behaviour because it enters the `if a == "No":`

*and "ERROR: You have not in-putted yes or no! "*

This is also expected. Here

```
    if a == "no":
        print("Ok, try again then. ")
# AND HERE:
    else:
        print("ERROR: You did not input yes or no! ")
```

It doesnt enter the if, because `"No"` is not equal to `"no"`. Therefore it enters the else and prints the error.

This should fix it

```
if a == "No":
    print("Ok, try again then. ")
elif a == "Yes":
    print("Cool name", name)
    break
elif a == "no":
    print("Ok, try again then. ")
else:
    print("ERROR: You did not input yes or no! ")\
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

You could check for `no` and `No` in one if, too, like this

```
if a == "no" or a == "No":
```

or like this

```
if a in ["no", "No"]
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps! I used if a == "no" or a == "No": and also did this for "Yes" and "yes". I am a beginner to any programming language being 15, its extremely confusing. Most of this I taught myself and other things my Computer Science teacher has taught me. So thanks! Currently working on a text based game :/. I have no clue how to do 2d or 3d world design but you have to start somewhere. This does make it simpler though. As python is straight forward xD. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That last else is only an else statement for the previous if.

Convert your statements to elif and it will work fine - but still this is not optimal coding.

Maybe try this after you define a:

```
a.lower()
```

This makes the answer in lowercase so that you don't need to test 'Yes' and 'yes' individually. It's simpler and more pythonic. You could also just use an or statement like this:

```
if a == 'yes' or  a == 'Yes' or a == 'Y' or a == 'y': 
    # do stuff
```